# For loops in Java (using Arrays)

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop

Create an array, type int, length 10. Initialize it with the multiple of 2.

Print it out to the console
Now print it in reverse order.

> Expected output: // (must use for loop)
>
> 2 4 6 8 10 12 14 16 18 20
>
> 20 18 16 14 12 10 8 6 4 2

This is what I have done so far :

```
    int [] values = new int [10];
    for (int i=2 ; i <= values.length; i ++)
    {
        if (i%2 == 0)
        System.out.println(i);
    }
```

Output: 2 4 6 8 10

It seems it only print up to the value of 10, but how do i get it to print a length of 10?

Comment: You never used your array. That's a hint.

Comment: You're not initializing the array at all, you're just displaying the numbers.

Comment: To pour water out of a cup you must first put the water in the cup.  To print the array you must first add things to the array.  I assume you're just starting out so you might not know about the api.  It's your friend, it has a record of all methods and how they work.  I'll link the java api for arrays, good luck :) https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html

Comment: thanks for your input everyone! we just briefly started arrays so your hints really helped fill in the gaps :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Create an array, type int, length 10. Initialize it with the multiple of 2.

In your code snippet you are not `Initializing` the array but simply printing the values to the console. You'll have to initialize it using either the loop or as follows:

```
int[] values = {2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18, 20};
```

If you want it to be initialized by writing the loop then here is the corrected code snippet:

```
public static void main (String[] args) throws Exception {
    int[] values = new int[10];
    values[0] = 2;
    System.out.print(values[0]);
    for (int i = 1; i < values.length; i++) {
        values[i] = values[i-1] + 2;
        System.out.print(" " + values[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you everyone for you help! Yeah our teacher literally spent about 20 mins skimming over arrays so all your input helped make this make a little but more sense.

Answer (score 1):

```
public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int[] arr = new int[10];      //declaring arr
        arr[0] = 2;       //giving arr a start point

        for(int i = 1 ; i<arr.length;i++)     //set values for arr
            arr[i] = arr[i-1] +2;        //each value is previous value + 2
        for(int i = 0; i<arr.length;i++)
            System.out.print(arr[i] + " ");     //prints it from 0 to 9
        System.out.println();
        for(int i = 0;i<arr.length;i++)
            System.out.print(arr[9 - i]+ " ");    //prints it backward
    }
```

Descriptions are on the code.

Answer (score 0):

```
int [] values = new int [10];
    for (int i=0 ; i <= values.length; i++)
    {
        values[i] = (i+1)*2; //initialize
    }
//Now iterate and print
```